# MS Teams Bot invite Call Queue as Participant

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, call-queue

I have a communications bot on MS Teams. The idea is that a user can call this bot who will then invite an agent to the call after gathering some information on the caller. The bot has some other mediating roles so i would like for it to stay in the call.
So far I have been able to invite regular users to the call but for applications, such as the call queue and auto attendant, I have been returned an 403 Error code.
This is how I tried it.

```
        const requestConfig = {
        "headers": {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
    }

    const requestBody = {
        "participants": [
          {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.invitationParticipantInfo",
            "identity": {
              "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
              
              "application": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identity",
                "displayName": "Call Queue",
                "id": queueId
              }
            }
          }
        ],
      }
```

In this post [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548543/graph-api-transfer-call-to-call-queue) it was mentioned that it might be possible to redirect an unanswered call to the queue, but I have not yet been able to reproduce this.
Highly appreciate feedback.

Comment: have you figured out in the end how to invite a Teams Call Queue to an ongoing call (not transfer or redirect to CallQueue)? I am attempting to build a similar solution and I ran into the same problem: can invite individual participants but not a Call Queue. I have tried to invite the Call Queue even manually in the Teams Desktop client but the Call Queue leaves the call the moment it's connected.

Comment: @Flav I does not seem to be possible to create calls unless the other party is a "user".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For redirecting to auto attendants or call queues use the "applicationInstance" identity.

```js
const requestBody = {
    "targets": [{
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.invitationParticipantInfo",
        "identity": {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",

            "applicationInstance": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identity",
                "displayName": "Call Queue",
                "id": queueId
            }
        }
    }],
}
```

Edit: See the documentation of the request here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-redirect?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#request

Comment: I have changed the identity and I get the right status code (202). The status text also reads "accepted". Unfortunatly though, the call does not go through. I have now also tried redirecting to an Auto Attendant, who I can call from my regular account, and a Testuser with the "user" identity with the same outcome each time.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I missed, that you used "participants". Please use "targets". I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:-

- Create a web.config file at the root of the app directory.
- Add the following code to web.config.

<system.webServer>

```
<!-- indicates that the index.js file is a node.js application 
to be handled by the iisnode module -->

<handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>

<!-- adds index.js to the default document list to allow 
URLs that only specify the application root location, 
e.g. http://mysite.antarescloud.com/ -->

<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
```

</system.webServer>